# Twitter Bootstrap Mobile navbar issues

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, twitter, navbar, nav

I'm new to HTMl, CSS and all of this. I'm trying to create a responsive website using Twitter Bootstrap, I like how the site looks and works on a desktop but the navigation bar will not open on a mobile device. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here's the website:
http://adtsite.co.nf/

Comment: What is your exact question?

Comment: I can't seem to get the mobile navigation to work, It shows up but nothing happens when I click it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re upload the boostrap. I've had this problem as well, re uploading almost always will fix your problem.